# Troubleshooting for problems when using Platypus Package(version 3.4.1) in R for BCR Repertoire Analysis

Tags: r, platypus

I am a graduate student majoring in immunology.
Recently, I've been working on single cell Sequence Data and trying to analyze BCR Sequence Data from 10x Chromium with the Package 'Platypus version 3.4.1'.
I'm stuck on the first step using function VDJ_GEX_matrix.
I copied and pasted the function wrote in vignettes as follows:

```
VDJ.out.directory.list[[1]] <- c("./BCR Data/VDJ5/")
GEX.out.directory.list <- list()
GEX.out.directory.list[[1]] <- c("./BCR Data/GEX5/")
vgm <- VDJ_GEX_matrix(VDJ.out.directory.list = VDJ.out.directory.list, GEX.out.directory.list = GEX.out.directory.list,GEX.integrate = T, VDJ.combine = T, integrate.GEX.to.VDJ = T, integrate.VDJ.to.GEX = T)
```

(VDJ5 and GEX5 are the direct output folder of CellRanger)

it resulted in an error like this:

```
Error in VDJ.proc$Nr_of_VJ_chains == 0 && VDJ.proc$Nr_of_VDJ_chains ==  : 
'length = 78' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

First I thought that there might be some problems in my files, so I tried same process with the example files given by the Platypus, but the result was same.
Maybe some structures or syntax in the function VDJ_GEX_matrix() is wrong or maybe other problems I  cannot catch.

How should I deal with this problem?

p.s. Is there any recommended packages for analyzing BCR Repertoires? (eg. clonotypes, somatic hyper-mutation rate, etc.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SO! Can you show the failing example from the package? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MichaelRoswell Oh, I edited the post. The input commands and the error results are shown in the post as in above.

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you share some data too?

Comment: @MichaelRoswell I used the data given as an example, link are as follows: https://polybox.ethz.ch/index.php/s/fxQJ3NrRSwiPSSo

Comment: Thanks Daniel... See the first comment link for how to include the data in your example in a streamlined way so others can reproduce your problem and help you troubleshoot.